# How can I show data frame at chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am taking the data from mongodb. I need to show languages at bar or pie chart with percentages but I could not do it. Here is my code so far.

```
library(mongolite)
library(ggplot2)

# Connect to mongolabs
con <- mongo("tweets", url = "mongodb://a12345:a12345@127.0.0.1:27017/newDatabase")

# Query data
mydata <- con$find(
  fields = '{"lang" : true}'
)

print(mydata)

options(max.print=1000000)
```

And console output:

[image]

Do I need to calculate each language's counts with for loop and have a form of something like that:

```
     lang  count
 1   eng    25
 2   tr     25
 3   de     50
```

Then, with a code like this? (ref: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-pie-chart-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization)

```
library(ggplot2)
# Barplot
bp<- ggplot(df, aes(x="", y=count, fill=lang))+
geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity")
bp
```

Or, is there an easier way?

Comment: Just `ggplot(df, aes(x=lang)) + geom_bar()` would do it

Comment: yeah, thanks.    ggplot(mydata, aes(x=lang)) + geom_bar()